# Can you run a laptop with a dead battery using only a power bank of appropriate size?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I have a MacBook Air (13", early 2014) with a dead battery (won't accept charge). I currently run it using the MagSafe power adapter. However, the magnetic connector is too easily disconnected causing the computer to turn off without being shut down. Can I use a power bank of appropriate amperage plugged into a USB-C 3.0 port on the laptop to safely power the laptop while I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Not in this case. The [MacBook Air (13", early 2014)](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp700) doesn’t have any USB C ports and none of the USB ports or the Thunderbolt port can be used for power.

A system needs a USB C port that specifically supports PD (Power Delivery) and I believe only MacBook Air models from 2018 onwards can do that. PD (Power Delivery) has nothing to do with USB 3.0 or any other USB standard; it is not inherent to USB ports.

Best to just get a new battery installed.

Comment: But if it has PD, can a power bank run it? I have a 2020 macair adn was searching for it.

Comment: @Marco Sure. If the 2020 MacBook Air uses USB C then it can be powered by a USB C power bank.